# FFmpeg HLS conversion cause increased file size

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I am trying to convert my MP4 file to HLS format while it stays as same quality.. But at the end my 60 mb video becomes 155mb. I use the code below. How to make the HLS size same as initial file while quality stays the same?

```
ffmpeg -i 10001.mp4 -profile:v baseline  
-start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls 10001.m3u8
```

Comment: You're re-encoding the video, using the baseline profile, which is least efficient. Switch to `main` or better yet, only copy the video.

Comment: @Gyan when I switched to main, it is 120 mb. It is still double amount. I deleted "-profile:v baseline" and it is still same. How to simply copy without any increase on the size?

Comment: Remove `-profile:v baseline` and add `-c:v copy`

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much. You saved tons of time and space!